# How to make opt in llvm invoke both my added llvm pass and the built-in passes

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, llvm-clang

I got confused when I read the instructions by [Adrian](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asampson/blog/clangpass.html) about invoking a custom LLVM pass:

1. Compile each source file to bitcode with `clang -c -emit-llvm code.c`.
2. Run your pass by itself with `opt -load mypass.so -mypass < code.bc > code_inst.bc`.
3. Run the rest of the standard optimizations with `opt -O3 < code_inst.bc > code_opt.bc`.
4. Compile the optimized bitcode into assembly with llc and then use your favorite assembler and linker to get the rest of the way to an executable.

Why is step 3 necessary? Does it imply that Step 2 only invokes "maypass" and omits all other system-default passes?

If so, is there a way to run both "mypass" and all the system-default passes in one single opt command?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experiment,

1. I can confirm that Step 2 will only invoke "mypass".
2. If you use

   opt -O3 -load mypass.so -mypass < code_inst.bc > code_opt.bc

Opt will first invoke the built-in passes, and then "mypass".

3. If you use

   opt -load mypass.so -mypass -O3 < code_inst.bc > code_opt.bc

Opt will first invoke "mypass", and then the built-in passes.

In summary, it is consistent with the [manual](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/opt.html):

> -{passname}
>
> opt provides the ability to run any of LLVM’s optimization or analysis passes in any order. The -help option lists all the passes available. The order in which the options occur on the command line are the order in which they are executed (within pass constraints).

In particular, "-O3" can be understood as a pre-defined set of passes.